# Workflow to Update Library Column with Data from List

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

When creating a new item within the library I want a workflow to lookup a field in a list and if it equals a column in my library I want to update another column in my library. The field I need to look up is a people/group picker but all I need is it to be pulled in as a string. Everytime I create the workflow condition it asks for a specific value which is not what I need.

Please help

Thank you.

Here is an example if it is not clear...

[image]

Comment: Your question was not very clear friend...

Comment: The picture should explain basically what I want to do but does not work.

Comment: Try this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59872/how-to-make-workflow-update-another-list-item-based-on-a-calculation-sp2010