# Update a list item in a list in a root site from a sub site

Tags: sharepoint-designer, 2016, updatelistitems, workflow-settings

I am currently working on SharePoint 2016 on premises,

I have a situation where in the root site, I have a list A which has a content type X and one of the fields is counter (starts with 1).  From a sub-site there is another list B, which has a lookup to List A, when a user creates an item on list B the counter related to the item in List A should be updated.  I am trying to see the different options I have.  The problem is I cannot use provider hosted apps since it is against policies so no event receivers can be created via server side code.

I was thinking of doing this via workflow via SPD, can anyone tell me if this is a good idea, and if yes provide me with some knowledge on this since I have never done any workflows before.

Answer (score 0):

1. One way I see is you can customize your subsite `list B` forms.

   In that you will add your script and update items of root site `list A` items.

   Script will have `PreSaveAction` method which will be called when you add/update item.

   Inside that method you can get item from the root site `list A` and update its value as per your need.

   Look here for code snippets for [How to: Create, Update, and Delete List Items Using JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185011(v=office.14).aspx)
2. The other way you could use is workflow. Here is the steps to [Create a workflow for SharePoint](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/sharepoint-designer-2013-create-a-list-workflow-in-sharepoi/).

   Once you are able to create workflow you can see here for more info about [How you can update list item](http://3sharp.com/blog/updating-list-items-with-sharepoint-designer/) in worklfow.

   Also check this link: [How to make workflow update another list item based on a calculation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/59872/how-to-make-workflow-update-another-list-item-based-on-a-calculation-sp2010).

In my opinion I would prefer first option. But you can go ahead with any you would like as both options are good to go. There might be other ways also available but I feel this are two best options for you.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I will try to check about option 1, since option 2 would need that I would use rest services via a workflow, since list A resides in a root web, the SPD would not let me update it that easily.  Also regarding Option 1, I want to update list A listItem counter, once an item is saved.  I doubt that the PreSaveActions will help in this case.  Are there any after save methods related, without having to rewrite all the saving functionality in the custom form?

Comment: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/91854/what-is-the-difference-between-presaveaction-and-presaveitem-on-sharepoint-l Check this thread.

Comment: When you update item in `list B`. Update form there (for list B only), specify `PreSaveAction` or `PreSaveItem` as per your need and update `list A` entry  by REST or JSOM. This should work for your requirement.